# How to use bodyParser in express to get JSON from a parsed document from PapaParse on the client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch, body-parser

For the past few days I have been struggling with this and asking individual questions but no answer has taken the whole thing into account so Im going to tell you the whole issue.

The program is Javascript, Node, Express, EJS, PapaParser, bodyParser, RethinkDB, I have socket.io but I havent done anything with it yet. There is no AJAX. I am running in a cloud9 instance for what thats worth.

I need to load my data into my application daily so I wrote a small backend GUI to load files with, a dialog box to show what the output would look like. Then a button to confirm and send it to my database.

Currently everything is working but the button's functionality to the database. I have my EJS template for my backend and this is the code:

```
<form class="import" method="POST" enctype="mutipart/form-data" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="fileToRead" multiple>
            <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">
                You can enter one day or multiple days. Please see another import for anything other than daily data</small><br>
            <button id="importButton">I like what I see..Send!</button>
        </div>
    <!-- this line... the id is in the importData.js file, overflow-y: auto is what makes this section scrollable-->
    <p id="editor" style="border: 1px black dotted; width: 100%; height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;">Hopefully see something here</p>
    </form>
```

I have another javascript file that has the code for parsing the CSV file here is that code:

```
document.getElementById("importButton").addEventListener("click",function(){
//creates a var for the first file.
//Gets the number to loop through
var input = document.getElementById("fileToRead");
console.log(input.files.length);
for(var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++){
    var files = input.files[i];
        Papa.parse(files, {
        header:true,
        dynamictyping:true,
        complete:function(results){
            console.log(results);
            document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(results);
            //uses another function (defined below) to import into rethinkDB
            fetch('https://development-cansliming.c9users.io/canadmin',{
                method:'POST',
                body: {results}
            }); //End fetch()

            console.log(JSON.stringify(results.data));
```

I am omitting closing curly braces for brevity sake.

I am using bodyParser (or trying to) this is express code:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/canadmin", jsonParser, function(req,res){
var data = req.body;
console.log(data);
//  r.db('cansliming').table('daily').insert( r.json(data) ).run(err, );
res.redirect("canadmin");
});
```

All I get in my console.log is {} which leads me to believe that I am not using fetch or bodyparser correct. I can see the object in my console.log correctly in the browser before it sends to fetch.

I would really appreciate the help, I have spent probably 20 hours trying to work on this, Ive gone through fetch, bodyParser, Express documents to no end.

Comment: What is the `jsonParser` middleware specified on `app.post('/canadmin', jsonParser, function(req, res) {});`? Also, if you want to use `JSON` as the request type, you need to make sure that you're sending through the `Content-Type` header as `application/json`. Your current form is submitting, `multipart/form-data`, if you want to use `multipart/form-data` as the header than you'll need to use multipart middleware like [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). Since you're uploading files, I'd look into using `multer`, `body-parser` is for stringified data requests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 
I am currently using the application /json and its not working, as for the middleware I saw that in some code tutorial so I tried it, it appears to be something to tell bodyParser that its parsing JSON. Like I said there are a ton of tutorials out there. I dont want to user multipart/form-data I just want the thing to work, I'll use whatever is easiest or whatever will work.